# How to skip failed test cases using TestNG

Tags: selenium2, testng

How to Skip the failed test cases and to execute the remaining test cases when  using Selenium, Java  and TestNG.

Comment: please provide some answer..

Comment: @sameerjoshi - If so then please mark question as duplicate and share reference link so that OP can refer.

Comment: could you please share the link

Comment: @Surya - Please refer http://seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/skip-test-in-testng

Comment: @sameerjoshi I have to agree with Helping Hands - if there's value in having this question *here* (regardless of it exists elsewhere), then let's make a canonical question and answer for it. If it exists elsewhere *on this site* let's mark it as a duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: @sameerjoshi I cleaned up your answer, but you deleted it. I have to admit, I liked your answer!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know what all test cases  have failed in execution then add testng annotation `@Test(Enabled=False)`

```
@Test(enabled=false)
public void testCaseEnabling(){
    throw new RuntimeException("I'm Not Ready, please don't execute me");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, only when you run your suite once you can have failed test cases.
When we execute the suite with testng, some reports(HTML, XML and etc) are generated which can be further utilized.

1. testng-failed.xml
2. testng-results.xml, etc

**Solution**

The *testng-failed.xml* contains all the failed test cases (a.k.a your test methods). You can go to your test methods and disable the test methods by using the enabled parameter with Test annotation.

**OR**

You can make a copy of *testng-results.xml* and modify it. It contains all the test cases that have skipped, failed or passed.